# CSS - Absolute and Relative Position with image fader

Tags: javascript, css, image, css-position

I'm working with an image fader program, but I'm not understanding absolute positioning.  I have the images fading nicely and resizing the way I want if the screen resizes.  but I have 2 problems. Div#2 gets covered up by the images. I want div2 to always appear below the image div.  Also, I have control buttons on the images. I want them in the middle.  I thought using top:50% would do that, but it's not.  Here's an example...

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,5000);

function nextSlide(){goToSlide(currentSlide+1);}

function previousSlide(){goToSlide(currentSlide-1);}

function goToSlide(n){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';}

var next = document.getElementById('next');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

next.onclick = function(){nextSlide();};
previous.onclick = function(){previousSlide();};
```

```css
#slides {position: relative}

.slide{ 
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-height:300px;
object-fit:cover;
opacity: 0; 
box-sizing:border-box;
transition: opacity 2s;}


.showing{opacity: 1;}

.controls{
background: transparent;
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #555;
width: 30px;
position: absolute;
}

.controls:hover{ opacity:.5}

.fadenext{right: 10px; top: 50%;}
.fadeprev{left:  10px; top: 50%;}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div id="slides">
   <img src='https://www.panotools.org/dersch/Monp.JPG' class="slide showing">
   <img src='https://www.panotools.org/dersch/StBp.JPG'  class="slide">
 
   <button class="controls fadeprev" id="previous">&lt;</button>
   <button class="controls fadenext" id="next">&gt;</button>
</div>


<div style='margin-top:40px;border:1px solid red;width:200px;height:100px'>
This is Div # 2</div>
```

Comment: where do you want div#2 to be and where do you want the controls to be?

Answer (score 0):

I've amended your snippet to fix your issues.

- Adding `margin-top` instead of `top` will fix your issue with the
  controls.
- Div 2 will now always remain below your slider.

*P.S. I moved your div2 inline styles to keep it neat.*

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 5000);

function nextSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function previousSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}

var next = document.getElementById('next');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

next.onclick = function() {
  nextSlide();
};
previous.onclick = function() {
  previousSlide();
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slides {
  position: relative
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
}

.controls {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.controls:hover {
  opacity: .5
}

.fadenext {
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.fadeprev {
  left: 10px;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.div2 {
  margin-top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div id="slides">
  <img src='https://www.panotools.org/dersch/Monp.JPG' class="slide showing">
  <img src='https://www.panotools.org/dersch/StBp.JPG' class="slide">

  <button class="controls fadeprev" id="previous">&lt;</button>
  <button class="controls fadenext" id="next">&gt;</button>
</div>


<div class="div2">This is Div # 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better, but there's still a problem.  If you make the screen size really narrow (like if viewing on a phone), div2 still get's sucked up under the images.   The control buttons also go off center when the screen gets narrow, but the buttons are not too big of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to use % based positions when you use "top" style. So to achieve what you want to do, use margin-top instead. As shown below:

```
.fadenext{right: 10px; margin-top: 25%;}
.fadeprev{left: 10px; margin-top: 25%;}
```

And for your div2, just change it's style to:

```
margin-top: 50%
```

Comment: How is your answer different from my mine? :P

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see your answer because you posted the whole code I thought it might be somewhat different. While I tried to mention him where exactly to make change.